# cracked photo on webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I can add item to the mysql server and upload photo on the server folder using form_upload.php  but the photo cannot display on the view_data.php. I already set the file permission to 777 but still not working.

Here is my form_upload php and view_data.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<title>Image Upload</title>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <form action="form_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
        <table width="350" border="0" align="center">
        <legend>Image Information Entry

          <tr><td><label>Title<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
          <td align="center"><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title"></br></td></tr>

          <tr><td><label>Description<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
          <td align="center"><input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description"></br></td></tr>

          <tr><td><label>Username<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
          <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"></br></td></td>

          <tr><td><label>Mobile Number<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
          <td align="center"><input type="text" name="mobilenumber" class="input-small" placeholder="mobilenumber"></br></td></tr>

          <tr><td><label>Address<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
          <td align="center"><input type="text" name="address" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="address"></br></td></tr>

          <tr><td><label for="file">Upload Image:</label></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br></td></tr>  
          <tr><td>&nbsp;  </td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        <a href="view_data.php?o=0" class="btn btn-primary">View Gallery</a></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2"> &nbsp </td></tr>      
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">        
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$con=mysqli_connect("local","user","pass","table");

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $mobilenumber=$_POST['mobilenumber'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $file=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $size= $_FILES["file"]["size"];

if( empty($title) || empty($description) || empty($mobilenumber) || empty($address) || empty($file))
{
    echo "<label class='err'>All field is required</label>";
}
    elseif(!is_numeric($mobilenumber))
    {
    echo "<label class='err'>Mobile number must be numeric</label>";
    }
    elseif($size >40000)
    {
        echo "<label class='err'> Image size must not greater than 40kb </label>";
    }
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 40000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
        {
          if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
          {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
          } 

                if (file_exists("/test/upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
                {
                  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "Image upload already exist. ";
                } 
                else
                {
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                  "/home/tz005/public_html/test/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO item_image (title, description, username, mobilenumber, address, filename)
                    VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$username', '$mobilenumber', '$address', '$file')");
                echo "Image Information Successfully Saved!";
                }

        }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</td></tr>
        </legend>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<title>view image information</title>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="con2">
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","table");

        if (is_numeric($_GET['o']))
        {
            $o=$_GET['o'];
        }else {
            $o=0;
            }

        if ($o >=1){
            $prev=$o-1;
            } else{
                $prev=0;
            }


        $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item_image LIMIT $o, 1");
        $get_pic=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        $query2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT imageid FROM item_image");
        $get_pic2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
        $total=mysqli_num_rows($query2);

        if ($o <=$total){$next=$o+1;}

    ?>
    <?php do { ?>
    <table align="center" width="300" border=".5" bordercolor="#0B615E">
        <tr> <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo '<img src="/home/tz005/public_html/test/upload/filename' . $get_pic['filename'] . '" width="200" height="200"> '; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td width="60"> Details: </td> <td align="left" bordercolor="#0B615E"> <?php echo $get_pic['title']; ?>  &nbsp
        <?php echo $get_pic['description'];?>  &nbsp
      <?php echo $get_pic['username'];?> </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="60"> Mobile number:</td> <td align="left"><?php echo $get_pic['mobilenumber']; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td width="60"> Address: </td> <td align="left"><?php echo $get_pic['address']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> 
    <?php
    } while ($get_pic=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
    ?>
    <?php if ($o>0){ ?>
    <span><a href="view_data.php?o=<?php echo $prev; ?>">Previous</a></span> 
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($o < ($total - 1)){ ?>
    <span><a href="view_data.php?o=<?php echo $next; ?>">Next</a></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </td><tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"> &nbsp </td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="form_upload.php"> Back to Image Information Entry</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"cracked photo"*? What... is it something found in an old attic? Be more specific.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and use `var_dump()` to troubleshoot this.

Comment: _"I already set the file permission to 777 but still not working."_ these are the famous last words of every person who ever got their site hacked by someone bored and running an exploit script against your server. Please, do not do this because this is is NEVER THE SOLUTION.

Comment: sorry, cannot display picture in web page.

Comment: Did you check the page source and see if the path is right?

Comment: This `/home/tz005/public_html/test/upload/` should probably not be an absolute path. Use a relative path `test/upload/` or `../test/upload/` depending on the location of the folder. Or even `/test/upload/`

Answer (score 1):

Your image tag is pointing to your file system, it needs to point to a URL:

```
<img src="/home/tz005/public_html/test/upload/filename' . $get_pic['filename'] . '"
```

You should probably change that to:

```
<img src="/test/upload/'.$get_pic['filename'].'"
```

Comment: [`Just like I said`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751079/cracked-photo-on-webpage#comment36515795_23751079) 3 mins. prior.

Comment: Not even an upvote for my comment neither @Dagon boohoo - the nerve of some people.